# BCC32C and exception propagation: EExternalException

Tags: c++builder

Using BCC32C (CLANG) of Rad Studio Berlin, when an exception is propagated, it is converted to EExternalException. For example:

```
try
{
    MyDelphiFunc()
}
catch(Exception &)
{
    StopEngine();
    throw;
}
```

The 'throw' converts an 'Exception' raised in 'MyDelphiFunc' to 'EExternalException' instead of simply propagate it:

```
Project xx raised exception class EExternalException with message 'External exception 'EEFFACE'
```

It worked perfectly in the 'classic' Borland compiler BCC32. Is it a bug or I am missing something?

**UPDATE**

To replicate it, create a empty VCL Form project in Rad Studio. Go to Options and check off "classic" Borland compiler. Add a button in the form and then the following code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    try
    {
        throw Exception("test");
    }
    catch(Exception &)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

It works fine with BCC32 but it throws EExternalException in BCC32C.

I am using RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin Version 24.0.22858.6822

Comment: Seems like this is yet another "difference" between BCC32 and BCC32C.

Comment: Looks similar to [RSP-13219 Exception rethrow causes a crash in BCC32C](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13219) (which was marked as "fixed" in Berlin): "*Run with debugger - Access violation. Run without debugger - External exception EEFFACE*"

Comment: @Remy: It looks similar but I am not sure if it is the same. They claim this  bug was  verified in build 24.0.22328.6018, however I am using 24.0.22858.6822.

Comment: @kokokok : I would suggest you create a new bug report for this.